# Drag/Drop registration did not succeed

Tags: vb.net, exception

I've already looked up this problem and everything I've have found was referring to C# which might be similar to VB.NET in some cases but I couldn't figure out how to use these solutions in VB.net.

So, my problem is that I got that one machine (end-user) with Windows 7 Professional (x64) which throws this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Nie można zarejestrować elementu
>   DragDrop. ---> System.Threading.ThreadStateException: Bieżący wątek
>   musi być ustawiony na tryb jednow1tkowego    apartamentu, aby można
>   było wykonywać wywołania OLE. Upewnij się, że w funkcji Main jest
>   zaznaczony    element STAThreadAttribute.
>       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetAcceptDrops(Boolean accept)
>       --- Koniec œladu stosu wyj1tków wewnêtrznych ---
>       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetAcceptDrops(Boolean accept)
>       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
>       w System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
>       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)
>       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>       w System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
>       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>       w System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>       w System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

As part of it is in Polish I will explain it a bit. Basically in the beginning it says

> System.InvalidOperationException: DragDrop registration did not
>   succeed

and as far as I understand it there is some problem with Drag/Drop option in some DataGridView.

My guess is that it happens when running delegate which checks for notifications because that exception is shown on main form start (a bit after starting delegate) and it shows again after some time when the delegate runs again. I checked all forms which are open by this delegate and none of them has AllowDrop enabled for any control. However I'm using DragDrop in other forms which doesn't throw this exception.

My other guess is that it might be a problem on end-user's machine (not the program's problem) as that exception is never thrown on other hosts (most of them are Windows 10 x64, Pro and Home, and one Windows 7 x86 Professional). I use one install file for all those machines.

Other than that I've tried remote debugging with Visual Studio 2013 on that problematic host and that Exception was never thrown. It is only thrown when application is installed (which btw I tried reinstalling).

Any idea how can I get rid of that error?

Comment: That is a pretty gross mishap in a winforms app, pretty unlikely that it has anything to do with your code.  Especially so in vb.net since you don't directly control the apartment state yourself.  This user has a corrupt component installed on his machine, perhaps activated by OpenFileDialog.  But there are other ways.  Maybe he can rescue it with SysInternals' AutoRuns utility, but the blanket advice is to reformat the disk.  This is not your problem to solve.

Comment: Well, that kind of sucks because I just reinstalled that computer because it had Windows 10 with Menu Start button not working but what can I do. I will try reinstalling soon, thanks for help.